# Is there a config option for requirejs optimizer to not delete empty directories?

Tags: requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

I have a project structure that has an empty directory (probably auto-generated but required). Running the requirejs optimizer on this structure does not copy (this empty directory) it to the output build directory.
How can I tell the optimizer to preserve this directory while generating the output?

**Project Structure:**

```
ProjectName
ProjectName/src
ProjectName/src/main.js
ProjectName/src/controls
ProjectName/src/controls/dialog
ProjectName/src/controls/dialog/dialog.js
ProjectName/src/controls/table
ProjectName/src/controls/table/table.js
ProjectName/src/controls/menu //empty dir
```

**Build Config**

```
({
  appDir: "src",
  baseUrl: "./",
  mainConfigFile: 'src/main.js',
  optimize: "uglify2",
  optimizeCss: "standard",
  preserveLicenseComments: true
})
```

Comment: Do you mean that `r.js` is **deleting** a directory that exists before it is run, or that `r.js` is **not creating** a directory you want it to create?

Comment: r.js is deleting a directory (an empty one) that existed before it is run.

Comment: Your question says that it "ignores the empty directory". Deleting is different from ignoring.

Comment: Corrected the original post!

Comment: Ok, now it is making sense. Can you add the build config to the question?

Comment: @Louis Added source structure and config to the post.

Comment: Did you try using `keepBuildDir: true` in your configuration?

Comment: @Louis Yes, I have tried that and it does not work. That option is related to the output build directory to remove it or not on a rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an ideal solution, but you could try creating an empty `../menu/.preserve` file as a work around. Assuming r.js sees it, that should help.

Comment: Yes, my last resort would be to create an empty file in the directory but I am looking for any existing option that can preserve an empty directory and copy as is to the build output directory.